# Impact: Delete a View, Create table with same name

Tags: sql, oracle, view

So there was this VIEW in oracle named XYZ and somebody says, we are going to replace it with a TABLE of the same name.

What kind of an impact can this create to existing SQL's written on that view?
Is the syntax for querying a VIEW same as that for a TABLE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "... replace it with a table ..." I assume you mean that a table is created with the same data the view was referencing. In other words, the new table redundantly contains data from other tables (those that the view was referencing).

SELECT-Statements will not need to be changed - the syntax is the same.

**BUT:** The view will immediately reflect changes in underlying tables. The table obviously not - it will have to be kept in sync by triggers or application logic. So depending on the view, this might be a rather big change. Even more so if the view was updateable.

Example:

Suppose the view was defined as `... select a.key, b.name from a,b where b.key = a.b_ref`

Then selecting from the view will always reflect changes to tables `a` and `b`.

If you replace it by a table, you would have to update that new table every time you update table `a` or `b`.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to say by "The view will immediately reflect changes in underlying tables. The table obviously not". A table will immediately reflect changes to itself (e.g. inserts/updates/deletes) just as a view on that table would.

Comment: Sure, but as the view references a table (at least one), you have to update two tables after replacing it by a table. I might add an example.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the columns are identical in **Name DataType** and **DataLength**, then there will be no impact.

SQL SELECT statments essential treat VIEWS and TABLE as the same things.